# Cant upload to PyPi

Tags: python, module, upload, pypi

Im trying to upload my programming language project with pypi, and i have an error while running `py -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*`

i get an error in cmd, saying:
`myemail is an invalid value for Author-email. Error: Use a valid email address`

i've tried almost everything, and ive read every documentation, but i cant get it to work

(it isn't a problem with the setup.cfg file, because when i changed it, a different email popped up in the error)

Comment: did you try to provide a valid email address?

Comment: Can you show a part of your setup config file ?

Comment: replace `myemail` with a valid email address

Comment: yes, i did replace it with a valid email, yet it still doesnt work